# Excel VBA: Unexpected result with Range and Cells

Tags: excel, range, cells, vba

I'm using Excel 2013. In my code I refer I have to manipulate typical data in an Excel Sheet. For instance:

```
    **Names**  
       Ann  
       Jim  
       Tom  
       Liz
```

I don't want to include a *+1* in my code when refering to specific cells within my data set.

I.e., to get "Ann" I would rather use

```
Cells(1,1)
```

than

```
Cells (1+1,1)
```

So I define a Range excluding the headers:

```
Set R = Range(Cells(2,1),Cells(5,1)
```

And now this statement refers to "Ann"

```
R.Cells(1,1)
```

Next I want to refer to a "subrange" within my range *R*:

```
    R.Range(R.Cells(2,1), R.Cells(3,1))
```

But surprisingly, now, instead of the expected "Jim" and "Tom" (second to third cells in my range *R*), I get "Ann" and "Jim" (second to third in the **Excel sheet**).

Can anyone provide some insight about what I am missing here?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This is a classic case of not passing along inherited parentage. The `Cells` within `R.Range(Cells(2,1), Cells(3,1))` have no idea that they belong to `R` so they default to the [ActiveSheet property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff822753.aspx) which may or may not even be the worksheet that `R` is on (more problems there with a *Subscript out of range* error).

```
with R
    debug.print .Range(.Cells(2,1), .Cells(3,1)).address
end with
```

The [With ... End With statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wc500chb.aspx) is the easiest way to pass along inherited parentage. Note that `.Cells` and not `Cells` is used to pass on the reference. It could also be written as,

```
    debug.print R.Range(R.Cells(2,1), R.Cells(3,1)).address
```

Sample sub:

```
Sub Unexpected_result_with_Range_and_Cells()
    Dim R As Range

    Set R = Range(Cells(2, 1), Cells(5, 1))
    Debug.Print R.Address
    Debug.Print R.Cells(1, 1).Value

    With R
        Debug.Print .Range(.Cells(2, 1), .Cells(3, 1)).Address
        Debug.Print .Cells(2, 1).Value
        Debug.Print .Cells(3, 1).Value
    End With

End Sub
```

Results from the VBE's Immediate window:

```
$A$2:$A$5
Ann
$A$4:$A$5
Jim
Tom
```

Comment: I'm sorry to say that's not the case. That's the first thought I had, but after including the reference to "R" (I edited the code above, BTW), the behavior remains the same

Comment: Right... `$A$4:$A$5` is `Tom` and `Liz` but `R.Range(R.Cells(2, 1), R.Cells(3, 1))` should be `Jim` and `Tom`. BTW, I really appreciate the help